# What is 'Total number of users connected to the system: ' specifies in websphere logs?

Tags: oracle, websphere, maximo

We are using Maximo 6.2 with Websphere 6 version.
In systemOut.log file I can find the total number of connected users is keep on increasing day by day.

```
Server Host:xxxxx ,Server Name:MXServer  ,Number of Users:666
Total number of users connected to the system:666
Memory Total = 1073216000 ,Free = 676880592
```

But only 10 users have logged into the system.
Is it specifying any DB connection leak?

Comment: You can always check your v$session/gv$session in oracle.

Comment: I can see only 17 active sessions from v$session table

Comment: Then there is no connection leak in your database. You should, probably, check the documentation for your application server. It could be the amount of connections since the server startup, for example.

Comment: If it is an number of connections since the server startup, the number should increase continuously right?, but it is decreasing a bit in between and then increasing again

Answer (score 1):

This is generally a representation of what is in the maxsession table, as users time out or log out the count should decrease. In your web.xml do you have a session timeout defined?  If it is set to 0 then it's possible users are just closing out the browser rather then signing out of the application, then the session is never being timed out because there isn't one. If it is set to 0 you should define a time out to ensure inactive users are being removed from maxsession.

Comment: Hi shane..Thanks for your reply.
 I have checked the maxsession table and the inactive sessions are notcleared from the maxsession table
 since the server startup. In web.xml the session time out is set to 60 min, even though the inactive sessions
 are not getting cleared from the table, 
any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: Maximo 6.2 went EOS a very long time ago, but I do remember there being some issues around this. What version of 6.2 are you running, I believe the last release was 6.2.8 back in 2011.

Comment: We are using Maximo 6.2.3 version

Comment: You can consider running a daily escalation to delete sessions older than a certain number of days.